# Questions about using the Background Intelligent Transfer Service

Tags: installation, windows-installer, auto-update, microsoft-bits, bits-service

I have a few questions in regards to using the Background Intelligent Transfer Service (BITS) as a scheme to add auto-updating capabilities to a windows application.

1 - If a user disables the Windows Update process, does Windows disables BITS?

2 - How does BITS interact with firewalls (hardware and software)?

For example, I install a program FOO.exe, when I have it connect to the network, the Firewall prompts me, asking if I want to allow Foo.exe to access the network. Is BITS prompted in this manner, and if so, how is the prompt described?

3 - Can BITS be disabled/turned off via GROUP POLICY at the domain level?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1 - No. BITS is an external service which the Windows Update service DEPENDS on.

2 - BITS is an internal aspect of the OS, as such it is inherently trusted by software firewalls.

3 - Yes. BITS as an service is under the control of the GROUP POLICY for the domain.

Comment: Hey Stephen,
Would you be able to give any comments on this question of mine,
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1830811/using-clickonce-deployment-with-background-intelligent-transfer-service